# How to retrieve email addresses from my gmail account?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, gmail

I am writing an "Invite Users" feature for my website.

I wanted the user to enter his gmail credentials or facebook credentials, and I wanted to send emails to the friends he chooses from.

Although I found out that you cannot send privates messages to your friends on FB via the API.

How can I accomplish the same using google / gmail ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the Google Contacts API along with OAuth. Accepting the user's GMail ID and password on your own site is never a good idea. http://code.google.com/apis/contacts/